# Kibana 3 - Change color of diagram if count is about certain value

Tags: javascript, kibana

I've got a question about Kibana 3. I know that it is possible to create Dashboards via Javascript, now I am looking for a way, to change the color of a diagram if a value is about a predefined threshold. 
Is there a way to do something like that?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: As per my knowledge Kibana doesn't have support for color customization. They have added it to road-map https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1362 for 4.3.0 I wrote one chrome extension as a hack for one of my project to allow color customization, however it is not well-documented and is very specific. Source is available at https://github.com/abhas9/recolor-it

Comment: The diagrams in Kibana are of the jquery.flot package ... but these diagrams don't offer a possibility to change the background color of the canvas or something like that ..

Comment: I think there's no easy answer, because of this I created a "threshold" panel based on the states panel. In this panel you can insert a time range and a certain threshold. If the threshold is exceeded the panel changes the color to red. If anybody is interested in this panel, don't hesitate to contact me.